# Google Plus Domains Api Activities: insert 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-api-client, google-domain-api

I try to use insert activity request through this special form http://joxi.net/J2bykQQS4XYxXm

```
    {
  "object": {
    "originalContent": "LaLALaLALa"
  },
  "access": {
    "items": [
      {
        "type": "domain"
      }
    ],
    "domainRestricted": true
  }
}
```

but always I have 403 error in answer. http://joxi.net/DrllG33c4vnb5r

I tried to use user_id instead me but had same results :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, you are not doing this as part of a Google Domain. Now also known as "gsuite", this allows companies to be able to post messages that are visible to *other members of the same company*. This does **not** allow you to post messages that are available for most Google+ users to see.

There is no public API available from Google to let you post to the public Google+. There is an API available to select partners (such as HootSuite) which let them post to the public Google+, but they seem to be slow or reluctant to add additional partners.